# What’s the viewing order for new Doctor Who episodes *and* minisodes?

Tags: doctor-who, suggested-order

I’m currently re-watching new Who, in the hope of understanding what on earth is going on during the Christmas special.

In addition to the episodes themselves, in recent years the BBC has also produced several “minisodes” (I guess it’s hard to think up a good name for mini-episodes) which add a bit of context around some episodes (e.g. [Pond Life](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZkWjkvaKpA)), provide a bit of fun during BBC charity telethons (e.g. [Time Crash](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szuP0oBZX4g)), and occasionally portray pretty major plot points (e.g. [Night of the Doctor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EobSTIc-ywA)).

I’d like to watch these too, but I can’t find a definitive list of them, or an indication of where each one fits in. It’s hard enough keeping the time-travel straight in my head, let alone figuring out where these minisodes are meant to slot in.

What’s the correct in-universe episodes-plus-minisodes viewing order of new Who?

Comment: The online minisodes are called webisodes. Cause a + b = c...

Comment: Or just minisodes...

Comment: [This list](http://www.reddit.com/r/doctorwho/comments/10klcl/list_of_doctor_who_miniepisodes/) on reddit is good.

Comment: Download "Series Guide" for Android to see the list in Special Episodes section. Watch in the order they were released..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: ha ha! I’d have to use an Android device for that. I’m not some kind of savage, Sachin. (Although, for anyone taking a walk on the smartphone OS wild side, do you mean [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.umzing.DrWhoGuide&hl=en)?)

Comment: I believe they are known as tardisodes

Comment: @AnthonyX: and if any of them ever get re-made, we could call those Retardisodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia’s pages for each episode of the show do a good job of listing related minisodes.

For example, the Chronology section of [the page for *Last of the Time Lords*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_of_the_Time_Lords) indicates that *Time Crash* fits in after that episode.

Similarly, [the page for *The Snowmen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Snowmen) mentions the three “prequel” minisodes that lead into this episode.

Answer (score 14):

### Watch them in the order they were released.

They were released for immediate viewing, and while they aren't always in strict *chronological* order (though they usually are!) they're in the intended *narrative* order.

Especially for the episodes released under Moffat's direction (all of the Eleventh Doctor), you need to just let the timey-wimey wash over you and succumb to the emotion of the stories. He's not interested in making sense so much as he is in creating emotionally powerful narratives.

Try the [Doctor Who Resource Guide](http://www.drwhoguide.com/who.htm). It looks like they've got *everything*, including books, comics, and audio adventures. I don't see the Proms, but those aren't in any canon and really have no bearing on anything, even tangentially.

Comment: Good good. Where might I find their release order?

Comment: This is a good list with the original air dates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_serials

Comment: @NathanKinsinger: that’s spot on for the episodes, but it doesn’t seem to list the minisodes (unless I’m not seeing it).

Comment: Pond Life, Time Crash and Night of the Doctor and many others are there. Look at the Specials sections. For example Time Crash is under the heading Specials (2007) with Voyage of the Damned.

Comment: @NathanKinsinger: aha, yes you’re quite right.

Comment: The Wikipedia list is incomplete. It doesn't include all extra content, including the *Children in Need: Born Again* episode or Tardisodes. The Resource Guide linked to in the OP seems to be accurate, but is not easily navigable. The list linked to [here](http://www.thetvdb.com/?tab=seasonall&id=78804&lid=7) by the second-highest answer is accurate and more easily navigable.

Answer (score 7):

[This episode list](http://www.thetvdb.com/?tab=seasonall&id=78804&lid=7) on thetvdb.com includes specials / minisodes / webisodes, along with air dates. I suggest watching them in the same order.

```
Episode Number  Episode Name    Originally Aired

1 x 1   Rose    2005-03-26   
1 x 2   The End of the World    2005-04-02   
1 x 3   The Unquiet Dead    2005-04-09   
1 x 4   Aliens of London (1)    2005-04-16   
1 x 5   World War Three (2) 2005-04-23   
1 x 6   Dalek   2005-04-30   
1 x 7   The Long Game   2005-05-07   
1 x 8   Father's Day    2005-05-14   
1 x 9   The Empty Child (1) 2005-05-21   
1 x 10  The Doctor Dances (2)   2005-05-28   
1 x 11  Boom Town   2005-06-04   
1 x 12  Bad Wolf (1)    2005-06-11   
1 x 13  The Parting of the Ways (2) 2005-06-18   
Special Children in Need: Born Again    2005-11-18  
Special The Christmas Invasion  2005-12-25  
Special The Attack of the Graske    2005-12-25  
Special Tardisode 01: New Earth 2006-04-08  
2 x 1   New Earth   2006-04-15   
Special Tardisode 02: Tooth And Claw    2006-04-15  
2 x 2   Tooth and Claw  2006-04-22   
Special Tardisode 03: School Reunion    2006-04-22  
2 x 3   School Reunion  2006-04-29   
Special Tardisode 04: The Girl In The Fireplace 2006-04-29  
2 x 4   The Girl in the Fireplace   2006-05-06   
Special Tardisode 05: Rise of the Cybermen  2006-05-06  
2 x 5   Rise of the Cybermen (1)    2006-05-13   
Special Tardisode 06: The Age Of Steel  2006-05-13  
2 x 6   The Age of Steel (2)    2006-05-20   
Special Tardisode 07: The Idiot's Lantern   2006-05-20  
2 x 7   The Idiot's Lantern 2006-05-27   
Special Tardisode 08: The Impossible Planet 2006-05-27  
2 x 8   The Impossible Planet (1)   2006-06-03   
Special Tardisode 09: The Satan Pit 2006-06-03  
2 x 9   The Satan Pit (2)   2006-06-10   
Special Tardisode 10: Love And Monsters 2006-06-17  
2 x 10  Love and Monsters   2006-06-17   
Special Tardisode 11: Fear Her  2006-06-17  
2 x 11  Fear Her    2006-06-24   
Special Tardisode 12: Army of Ghosts    2006-06-24  
2 x 12  Army of Ghosts (1)  2006-07-01   
Special Tardisode 13: Doomsday  2006-07-01  
2 x 13  Doomsday (2)    2006-07-08   
Special The Runaway Bride   2006-12-25  
3 x 1   Smith and Jones 2007-04-01   
3 x 2   The Shakespeare Code    2007-04-07   
3 x 3   Gridlock    2007-04-14   
3 x 4   Daleks in Manhattan (1) 2007-04-21   
3 x 5   Evolution of the Daleks (2) 2007-04-28   
3 x 6   The Lazarus Experiment  2007-05-05   
Special The Infinite Quest  2007-06-30  
3 x 7   42  2007-05-19   
3 x 8   Human Nature (1)    2007-05-26   
Special Doctor Who: A Celebration Concert   2007-05-28  
3 x 9   The Family of Blood (2) 2007-06-02   
3 x 10  Blink   2007-06-09   
3 x 11  Utopia (1)  2007-06-16   
3 x 12  The Sound of Drums (2)  2007-06-23   
3 x 13  Last of the Time Lords (3)  2007-06-30   
Special Children in Need: Time Crash    2007-11-16  
Special Voyage of the Damned    2007-12-25  
4 x 1   Partners in Crime   2008-04-05   
4 x 2   The Fires of Pompeii    2008-04-12   
4 x 3   Planet of the Ood   2008-04-19   
4 x 4   The Sontaran Stratagem (1)  2008-04-26   
4 x 5   The Poison Sky (2)  2008-05-03   
4 x 6   The Doctor's Daughter   2008-05-10   
4 x 7   The Unicorn and the Wasp    2008-05-17   
4 x 8   Silence in the Library (1)  2008-05-31   
4 x 9   Forest of the Dead (2)  2008-06-07   
4 x 10  Midnight    2008-06-14   
4 x 11  Turn Left   2008-06-21   
4 x 12  The Stolen Earth (1)    2008-06-28   
4 x 13  Journey's End (2)   2008-07-05   
Special The Next Doctor 2008-12-25  
Special Planet of the Dead  2009-04-11  
Special The Waters of Mars  2009-11-15  
Special The End of Time (1) 2009-12-25  
Special The End of Time (2) 2010-01-01  
Special The Ultimate Guide  2010-04-17  
Special Tonight's the Night 2009-05-23  
5 x 1   The Eleventh Hour   2010-04-03   
Special Meanwhile in the TARDIS (1) 2010-11-09  
5 x 2   The Beast Below 2010-04-10   
5 x 3   Victory of the Daleks   2010-04-17   
5 x 4   The Time of Angels (1)  2010-04-24   
5 x 5   Flesh and Stone (2) 2010-05-01   
Special Meanwhile in the TARDIS (2)     
5 x 6   The Vampires of Venice  2010-05-08   
5 x 7   Amy's Choice    2010-05-15   
5 x 8   The Hungry Earth (1)    2010-05-22   
5 x 9   Cold Blood (2)  2010-05-29   
5 x 10  Vincent and the Doctor  2010-06-05   
5 x 11  The Lodger  2010-06-12   
5 x 12  The Pandorica Opens (1) 2010-06-19   
5 x 13  The Big Bang (2)    2010-06-26   
Special A Christmas Carol   2010-12-25  
Special Space (1)   2011-03-18  
Special Time (2)    2011-03-18  
Special The Impossible Astronaut Prequel    2011-03-25  
Special Doctor Who: Rewind - Trust your Doctor  2011-04-23  
6 x 1   The Impossible Astronaut (1)    2011-04-23   
6 x 2   Day of the Moon (2) 2011-04-30   
Special The Curse of the Black Spot Prequel 2011-04-30  
Special Doctor Who in America   2011-04-30  
6 x 3   The Curse of the Black Spot 2011-05-07   
6 x 4   The Doctor's Wife   2011-05-14   
6 x 5   The Rebel Flesh (1) 2011-05-21   
6 x 6   The Almost People (2)   2011-05-28   
Special A Good Man Goes to War Prequel  2011-05-28  
6 x 7   A Good Man Goes to War (1)  2011-06-04   
Special Best of the Doctor  2011-08-13  
Special Best of the Monsters    2011-08-27  
Special Let's Kill Hitler Prequel   2011-08-15  
6 x 8   Let's Kill Hitler (2)   2011-08-27   
Special Best of the Companions  2011-09-03  
6 x 9   Night Terrors   2011-09-03   
6 x 10  The Girl Who Waited 2011-09-10   
6 x 11  The God Complex 2011-09-17   
Special Bad Night   2011-11-22  
Special Good Night  2011-11-22  
Special First Night 2011-11-22  
Special Last Night  2011-11-22  
Special Up All Night    2011-11-22  
6 x 12  Closing Time    2011-09-24   
Special The Wedding of River Song Prequel   2011-09-26  
6 x 13  The Wedding of River Song   2011-10-01   
Special The Doctor, the Widow and the Wardrobe  2011-12-25  
Special Good as Gold    2012-05-24  
Special The Science of Doctor Who   2012-08-04  
Special The Women of Doctor Who 2012-08-11  
Special The Timey-Wimey of Doctor Who   2012-08-18  
Special The Destinations of Doctor Who  2012-08-25  
Special Pond Life (1): April    2012-08-27  
Special Pond Life (2): May  2012-08-28  
Special Pond Life (3): June 2012-08-29  
Special Pond Life (4): July 2012-08-30  
Special Pond Life (5): August   2012-08-31  
Special Asylum of the Daleks Prequel    2012-09-02  
7 x 1   Asylum of the Daleks    2012-09-01   
7 x 2   Dinosaurs on a Spaceship    2012-09-08   
Special The Making of the Gunslinger (A Town Called Mercy Prequel)  2012-09-09  
7 x 3   A Town Called Mercy 2012-09-15   
7 x 4   The Power of Three  2012-09-22   
Special Doctor Who in the U.S.  2012-09-29  
7 x 5   The Angels Take Manhattan   2012-09-29   
Special The Snowmen 2012-12-25  
Special The Last Day of the Ponds   2012-09-29  
Special Children in Need: The Great Detective   2012-11-16  
Special Doctor Who: P.S.    2012-10-12  
Special Vastra Investigates: A Christmas Prequel    2012-12-17  
Special The Bells of Saint John: A Prequel  2013-03-23  
7 x 6   The Bells of St John    2013-03-30   
Special The Battle of Demon's Run — Two Days Later  2013-03-25  
Special The Companions  2013-03-31  
7 x 7   The Rings of Akhaten    2013-04-06   
7 x 8   Cold War    2013-04-13   
7 x 9   Hide    2013-04-20   
7 x 10  Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS 2013-04-27   
7 x 11  The Crimson Horror  2013-05-04   
7 x 12  Nightmare in Silver 2013-05-11   
Special She Said, He Said (The Name of the Doctor Prequel)  2013-05-11  
Special Clarence and the Whispermen (The Name of the Doctor Prequel)    2013-05-27  
7 x 13  The Name of the Doctor  2013-05-18   
Special The Night of the Doctor 2013-11-14  
Special The Day of the Doctor   2013-11-23  
Special The Time of the Doctor  2013-12-25  
Special The Last Day    2013-11-20  
Special Clara and the TARDIS    2013-09-24  
Special Rain Gods   2013-09-24  
Special The Inforarium  2013-09-24  
Special Earth Conquest (The World Tour) 2014-08-22  
Special Live Preshow    2014-08-23  
Special Deep Breath Prequel 2014-08-23  
8 x 1   Deep Breath 2014-08-23   
Special After Who Live  2014-08-23  
Special Doctor Who Extra: Deep Breath   2014-08-23  
8 x 2   Into the Dalek  2014-08-30   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Into the Dalek    2014-08-30  
8 x 3   Robot of Sherwood   2014-09-06   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Robot of Sherwood 2014-09-06  
8 x 4   Listen  2014-09-13   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Listen    2014-09-13  
8 x 5   Time Heist  2014-09-20   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Time Heist    2014-09-20  
8 x 6   The Caretaker   2014-09-27   
Special Doctor Who Extra: The Caretaker 2014-09-27  
8 x 7   Kill the Moon   2014-10-04   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Kill the Moon 2014-10-04  
8 x 8   Mummy on the Orient Express 2014-10-11   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Mummy on the Orient Express   2014-10-11  
8 x 9   Flatline    2014-10-18   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Flatline  2014-10-18  
8 x 10  In the Forest of the Night  2014-10-25   
Special Doctor Who Extra: The Forest of the Night   2014-10-25  
8 x 11  Dark Water  2014-11-01   
Special Doctor Who Extra: Dark Water    2014-11-01  
8 x 12  Death In Heaven 2014-11-08   
Special Last Christmas  2014-12-25  
Special Doctor Who Extra: Last Christmas    2014-12-25  
Special Prologue    2015-09-11  
Special The Doctor's Meditation     2015-09-18  
9 x 1   The Magician's Apprentice (1)   2015-09-19   
9 x 2   The Witch's Familiar (2)    2015-09-26   
9 x 3   Under The Lake (1)  2015-10-03   
9 x 4   Before The Flood (2)    2015-10-10   
9 x 5   The Girl Who Died (1)   2015-10-17   
9 x 6   The Woman Who Lived (2) 2015-10-24   
9 x 7   The Zygon Invasion (1)  2015-10-31   
9 x 8   The Zygon Inversion (2) 2015-11-07   
9 x 9   Sleep No More   2015-11-14   
9 x 10  Face The Raven  2015-11-21   
9 x 11  Heaven Sent (1) 2015-11-28   
9 x 12  Hell Bent (2)   2015-12-05   
Special Doctor Who Extra: The Husbands of River Song    2015-12-25  
Special The Husbands of River Song  2015-12-25
```

Answer (score 0):

Doctor Who - Torchwood

Doctor Who: Series One (2005)

DW 1.1 : Rose
DW 1.2 : The End of the World
DW 1.3 : The Unquiet Dead
DW 1.4 : Aliens of London
DW 1.5 : World War Three
DW 1.6 : Dalek
DW 1.7 : The Long Game
DW 1.8 : Father's Day
DW 1.9 : The Empty Child
DW 1.10 : The Doctor Dances
DW 1.11 : Boom Town
DW 1.12 : Bad Wolf
DW 1.13 : The Parting of the Ways
DW 1.13.1 : Children in Need: Born Again

Doctor Who: Christmas 2005

DW 1.14 : The Christmas Invasion
SW 1.14.1 : Attack of the Graske

Doctor Who: Series Two (2006)

Tardisode 1
DW 2.1 : New Earth
Tardisode 2
DW 2.2 : Tooth and Claw
Tardisode 3
DW 2.3 : School Reunion
Tardisode 4
DW 2.4 : The Girl in the Fireplace
Tardisode 5
DW 2.5 : Rise of the Cybermen
Tardisode 6
DW 2.6 : The Age of Steel
Tardisode 7
DW 2.7 : The Idiot's Lantern
Tardisode 8
DW 2.8 : The Impossible Planet
Tardisode 9
DW 2.9 : The Satan Pit
Tardisode 10
DW 2.10 : Love & Monsters
Tardisode 11
DW 2.11 : Fear Her
Tardisode 12
DW 2.12 : Army of Ghosts
Tardisode 13
DW 2.13 : Doomsday

Torchwood: Series One (2006)

TW 1.1 : Everything Changes
TW 1.2 : Day One
TW 1.3 : Ghost Machine
TW 1.4 : Cyberwoman
TW 1.5 : Small Worlds
TW 1.6 : Countrycide
TW 1.7 : Greek Bearing Grifts
TW 1.8 : They Keep Killing Suzie
TW 1.9 : Random Shoes
TW 1.10 : Out of Time
TW 1.11 : Combat
TW 1.12 : Captain Jack Harkness
TW 1.13 : End of Days

Doctor Who: Christmas 2006

DW 2.14 : The Runaway Bride

Doctor Who: Series Three (2007)

DW 3.1 : Smith and Jones
DW 3.2 : The Shakespeare Code
DW 3.3 : Gridlock
DW 3.4 : Daleks in Manhattan
DW 3.5 : Evolution of the Daleks
DW 3.6 : The Lazarus Experiment
DW 3.7 : 42
DW 3.8 : Human Nature 
DW 3.9 : The Family of Blood
DW 3.10 : Blink
DW 3.10.1 : The Infinite Quest
DW 3.11 : Utopia
DW 3.12 : The Sound of Drums
DW 3.13 : Last of the Time Lords
DW 3.13.1 : Children in need: Time Crash

Doctor Who: Christmas 2007

DW 3.14 : Voyage of the Damned
DW 3.14.1 : Comic Relief: clash in class

Torchwood: Series Two (2008)

TW 2.1 : Kiss Kiss Bang Bang
TW 2.2 : Sleeper
TW 2.3 : To The Last Man
TW 2.4 : Meat
TW 2.5 : Adam
TW 2.6 : Rest
TW 2.7 : Dead Man Walking
TW 2.8 : A Day In The Death
TW 2.9 : Something Borrowed
TW 2.10 : From Out of the Rain
TW 2.11 : Adrift
TW 2.12 : Fragments
TW 2.13 : Exit Wounds

Doctor Who: Series Four (2008)

DW 4.1 : Partners in Crime
DW 4.2 : The Fires of Pompeii
DW 4.3 : Planet of the Ood
DW 4.4 : The Sontaran Stratagem
DW 4.5 : The Poison Sky
DW 4.6 : The Doctor's Daughter
DW 4.7 : The Unicorn and the Wasp
DW 4.8 : Silence in the Library
DW 4.9 : Forest of the Dead
DW 4.10 : Midnight
DW 4.11 : Turn Left
DW 4.12 : The Stolen Earth
DW 4.13 : Journey's End
DW 4.13.1 : At The Proms + Music of the Spheres

Doctor Who: Christmas 2008

DW 4.14 : The Next Doctor (+ Children need Preview)
DW 4.14.1 : Dreamland
DW 4.14.2 : John Barrowman - Tonight's The Night

Doctor Who: Easter 2009

DW 4.15 : Planet of the Dead

Doctor Who: Autumn Special 2009

DW 4.16 : The Waters of Mars

Torchwood: Series Three (2009)

TW 3.1 : Children of Earth: Day One
TW 3.2 : Children of Earth: Day Two
TW 3.3 : Children of Earth: Day Three
TW 3.4 : Children of Earth: Day Four
TW 3.5 : Children of Earth: Day Five

Doctor Who: Christmas 2009

DW 4.16.1 : The Wedding of Sarah Jane (The Sarah Jane Adventures crossover)
DW 4.17 : The End of Time (+ Children in need Preview)

Doctor Who: Series Five (2010)

DW 5.1 : The Eleventh Hour (+ Unreleased Scene)
DW 5.1.1 Meanwhile In The TARDIS 1
DW 5.2 : The Beast Below
DW 5.3 : Victory of the Daleks
DW 5.4 : The Time of Angels
DW 5.5 : Flesh and Stone (+ Unreleased Scene)
DW 5.5.1 : Meanwhile In The TARDIS 2
DW 5.6 : The Vampires of Venice
DW 5.7 : Amy's Choice
DW 5.8 : The Hungry Earth
DW 5.9 : Cold Blood
DW 5.10 : Vincent and the Doctor
DW 5.11 : The Lodger
DW 5.12 : The Pandorica Opens
DW 5.13 : The Big Bang
DW 5.13.1 : Death Of The Doctor (The Sarah Jane Adventures crossover)
DW 5.13.2 : At The Proms

Doctor Who: Christmas 2010

DW 5.14 : A Christmas Carol ( + Children in Need Special)
DW 5.14.1 : Night and the Doctor: Bad Night
DW 5.14.2 : Comic Relief: Space & Time
DW 5.14.3 : Night and the Doctor: Good Night
DW 5.14.4 : National Television Awards Special

Doctor Who: Series Six, Part One (2011)

DW 6.1 : The Impossible Astronaut + Prequel
DW 6.2 : Day of the Moon
DW 6.3 : The Curse of the Black Spot + Prequel
DW 6.4 : The Doctor's Wife
DW 6.5 : The Rebel Flesh
DW 6.6 : The Almost People
DW 6.7 : A Good Man Goes to War + Prequel

Torchwood: Series Four (2011)

TW 4.1 : Miracle Day: The New World
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 1
TW 4.2 : Miracle Day: Rendition
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 2
TW 4.3 : Miracle Day: Dead of Night
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 3
TW 4.4 : Miracle Day: Escape to L.A.
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 4
TW 4.5 : Miracle Day: The Categories of Life
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 5
TW 4.6 :: Miracle Day: The Middle Men
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 6
TW 4.7 : Miracle Day: Immortal Sins
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 7
TW 4.8 : Miracle Day: End of the Road
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 8
TW 4.9 : Miracle Day: The Gathering
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 9
TW 4.10 : Miracle Day: The Blood Line
Torchwood: Web of Lies: Episode 10

Doctor Who: Series Six, Part Two (2011)

DW 6.8 : Let's Kill Hitler + Prequel
DW 6.9 : Night Terrors
DW 6.10 : The Girl Who Waited
DW 6.11 : The God Complex
DW 6.12 : Closing Time + Night and the Doctor: Up All Night
DW 6.13 : The Wedding of River Song + Prequel
DW 6.13.1 : Death Is the Only Answer 
DW 6.13.2 : Night and the Doctor: First Night
DW 6.13.3 : Night and the Doctor: Last Night

Doctor Who: Christmas 2011

DW 6.14 : The Doctor, the Widow and the Wardrobe ( + Prequel, Children in Need Special)
DW 6.14.1 : Good as Gold
DW 6.14.2 : Pond Life

Doctor Who: Series Seven, Part One (2012)

DW 7.1 : Asylum of the Daleks + Prequel
DW 7.2 : Dinosaurs on a Spaceship
DW 7.3 : A Town Called Mercy + Prequel
DW 7.4 : The Power of Three
DW 7.5 : The Angels Take Manhattan
DW 7.5.1 : P.S.
DW 7.5.2 : The Inforarium

Doctor Who: Christmas 2012

DW 7.5.3 : The Snowmen (+ The Battle of Demon’s Run: Two Days Later, Vastra Investigates, Children in need: The Great Detective)
DW 7.5.4 : Rain Gods
DW 7.5.5 : Comic Relief: Call The Midwife crossover 2013

Doctor Who: Series Seven, Part Two (2013)

DW 7.6 : The Bells of Saint John + Prequel
DW 7.7 : The Rings of Akhaten
DW 7.8 : Cold War
DW 7.9 : Hide
DW 7.9.1 : Clara and the TARDIS
DW 7.10 : Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS
DW 7.11 : The Crimson Horror
DW 7.12 : Nightmare in Silver
DW 7.13 : The Name of the Doctor (+She Said, He Said, Clarence and the Whispermen, Strax Field Report)
DW 7.13.1 : The Ultimate Guide (opening and closing sketch only)
DW 7.13.2 : At The Proms

Doctor Who: 50th Anniversary Special 2013

DW 7.15 : The Day of the Doctor (+ The Night of the Doctor, The Last Day, Strax Field Report)

Doctor Who: Christmas 2013

DW 7.16 : The Time of The Doctor (+Strax Field Report)

Doctor Who: Series Eight (2014)

DW 8.1 : Deep Breath
DW 8.2 : Into the Dalek
DW 8.3 : Robot of Sherwood
DW 8.4 : Listen
DW 8.5 : Time Heist
DW 8.6 : The Caretaker
DW 8.7 : Kill the Moon
DW 8.8 : Mummy on the Orient Express
DW 8.9 : Flatline
DW 8.10 : In the Forest of the Night
DW 8.11 : Dark Water
DW 8.12 : Death in Heaven

Answer (score 0):

Short guide

2005.
Doctor Who: Series One.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2005.

2006.
Doctor Who: Series Two.
Torchwood: Series One.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2006.

2007.
Doctor Who: Series Three.
The Sarah Jane Adventures: Series One.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2007.

2008.
Torchwood: Series Two.
Doctor Who: Series Four.
The Sarah Jane Adventures: Series Two.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2008.

2009.
Doctor Who: Easter 2009.
Doctor Who: Autumn Special 2009.
Torchwood: Series Three.
The Sarah Jane Adventures: Series Three.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2009.

2010.
Doctor Who: Series Five.
The Sarah Jane Adventures: Series Four.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2010.

2011.
Doctor Who: Series Six, Part One.
Torchwood: Series Four.
Doctor Who: Series Six, Part Two.
The Sarah Jane Adventures: Series Five.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2011.

2012.
Doctor Who: Series Seven, Part One.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2012.

2013.
Doctor Who: Series Seven, Part Two.
Doctor Who: 50th Anniversary Special.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2013.

2014.
Doctor Who: Series Eight.
Doctor Who: Christmas 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice visualization of the order.
http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/watch-doctor-who-viewing-guide-perfect-order/

Comment: Yes, please [Bring the Content Here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/602/21267).

Comment: Downvoted. This visualisation does not include Tardisodes or Webisodes. The only special contect they do include are the Christmas specials.